# Apps doesn't show in activity tab after uploading using xcode 8

Tags: ios, build, app-store-connect, release, xcode8

I have recently updated my Xcode to Xcode 8 (not beta) and I was trying to upload an apps targeting IOS 8.2. I ran "upload to App Store" through Xcode and it said "submit successfully". However, when I check in the Activity tab after 24 hrs, the build is still not there. I tried to upload again and it gave me an error saying that the binary code is already exists. Does anyone know what the problem is?

I really appreciate any help you can give!

Comment: You normally have to wait for approval. Give it more than a day.

Comment: @Multinerd thanks for the reply. It usually shows up quickly on the activity tab and shows as processing. But this is the first time nothing shows on Activity. I hope it will show tomorrow. if not, I wouldnt know what to do.

Comment: it shows processing while uploading but when uploading done then its gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to upload again and it gave me an error saying that the binary
>   code is already exists.

When you upload again a new build, please ensure that **Build Number** is incremented.

> when I check in the Activity tab after 24 hrs, the build is still not
>   there.

First check you mail (associated with apple account) for build rejection details. Since you are using Xcode 8, iOS 10 SDK most probably you are missing mandatory usage description keys. You need to ask the use permission before access the user private data like contact number, photos , location , calendar , etc. in iOS 10 Apple is extending the scope of privacy control. You have to declare in Info.plist file access of any private data. [Reference for more details here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html)

Comment: Thanks @byJeevan! I checked the email and it gave me the reason they rejected my build.

Answer (score 1):

**There might many reasons for that. I have faced same issue and my solution was:**

Check informations in **Info.plist** ,Privacy Descriptions like  Calender , Camera , PhotoLibrary or build code or version code are effected factors.

**Or other issue may be in xcode - 9.1**

- If you haven't added proper appicon in asset with 1024 * 1024.
- Appicon can't be transparent nor contain an alpha channel.

If any query, Please ask further